# How to save a cv2.aruco.Dictionary object in a file and read it?

Tags: python, opencv, pickle, aruco

So I try to save a cv Dictionary in a file, because I access a the python function via Matlab and it always generates the same Dictionary when I call the function. So I want to safe the Dictionary in a file, where I can access it from python without generating it first.

I saw this post [Reading cv2.aruco.Dictionary from a yaml file issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75945130/reading-cv2-aruco-dictionary-from-a-yaml-file-issue) and the saving works, but when I tried the code which is commend below in the post:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import json


aruco_dict = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_100)

with open('DictionaryFile.yml', "w") as FILE:
    FILE.write(json.dumps({
        "marker_size" : aruco_dict.markerSize,
        "bytes_list": aruco_dict.bytesList.tolist(),
        "max_corr": aruco_dict.maxCorrectionBits,
    }, indent=4))


with open('DictionaryFile.yml', "r") as FILE:
    data = json.loads(FILE.read())
    loaded_bytes = np.array(data["bytes_list"], dtype=np.uint8)
    loaded_dict = cv2.aruco.Dictionary(
        len(loaded_bytes),
        data["marker_size"],
        data["max_corr"]
    )
    loaded_dict.bytesList = loaded_bytes
```

and I get this error:
loaded_dict.bytesList = loaded_bytes
cv2.error: Conversion error: value
How do I solve this conversion problem?